# Couchbase nested objects Type

Tags: java, json, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I'm trying to find out the best way to get the type of a nested object in a couchbase document.

I have this document :

```
{
  "storeType": {
    "name": "Store"
  },
  "name": "Store",
  "_class": "common.domain.Store",
  "categories": [
    {
      "name": "Series",
      "displayable": false,
      "active": false,
      "highlights": [
        {
          "name": "Spiderman",
          "active": true
        },
        {
          "name": "Spiderman2",
          "active": true
        }
      ],
      "categoryId": "SERIES"
    }
  ],
  "storeId": "STORE::10",
  "order": 1
}
```

Spring data uses _class to find out the hole document type.

My question is :

How can I find the precise type of each object in categories list?

Thx a lot

Comment: What is the type of the nested object in your example?

Comment: Here I have a Store containing a list of categories (which is an inherited class) and each category has a list of highlights.

Comment: Even with Spring Data I always add a type field to all my documents. It really helps. Also are you trying to get it through N1QL or a Spring Data repository?

Comment: It's through N1QL. What we are doing typically is to use Spring Data for all simple queries and use the java client  to perform more sophisticated queries (nested objects clearly).
So far we have two issues : Updating a second level nested objects through N1QL and retriving the type of the nested object (to avoid parsing the N1qlQueryResult)

Comment: Found the query to make the update. We used the collection operator WITHIN : UPDATE bucket b 
USE KEYS "Store::1" 
   SET h.active = false FOR h WITHIN b.categories when h.cbHighlightId = "Highlight::1" END . Highlight is not a Document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the query to make the update. We used the collection operator WITHIN : UPDATE bucket b USE KEYS "Store::1" SET h.active = false FOR h WITHIN b.categories when h.cbHighlightId = "Highlight::1" END . Highlight is not a Document